# Mailchimp No Host Exception when Subscribing Email to A List

Tags: rest, mailchimp, subscription, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to send a subscription call, but got an error saying the the URL is invalid.

This is the URL I used:

```
https://us14.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<list-id>/members/
```

then I get this back in the response:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Invalid URL</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <H1>Invalid URL</H1>
        The requested URL "http&#58;&#47;&#47;&#37;5bNo&#37;20Host&#37;5d&#47;3&#46;0&#47;lists&#47;41e44e1bde&#47;members&#47;", is invalid.
        <p>
        Reference&#32;&#35;9&#46;cc6a1db8&#46;1483891456&#46;16189371
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

which translates to:

```
http://[No Host]/3.0/lists/<list-id>/members/
```

us14 is definitely the right data center according to the documentation so I'm not quite sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that if you set HTTP header field "Host" in the request, it will always return this error. I tested this out by removing every fields one-by-one and this was the only one that caused an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Many environments use the Host header for stuff like virtual sites where you are running more than one website behind the same IP Address (i.e. api.mailchimp.com and www.mailchimp.com *could be* on the same server) It is definitly possible for an error to be received if you set an invalid host since their proxies can't route it correctly. Normally, the host header is set automatically by the browser or HTTP client and usually not something you would override.

Are you still having trouble? If so, would be useful to see a screenshot of something like PostMan or https://ApiRequest.IO to see what your inputs are.